# COUNT how many times the value of a row has appeared in the table and conditionate the result to a selection mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, count, selection

As the title says, how can I count how many times the value of a row has appeared in the table and conditionate the result to only show those that have appeared a certain number of time. For example, in this case I'd like to select only the rows that have a test value that has appeared with all  "modelo" values.

[image]

Comment: The explanation is not very clear, at least to me, please provide a **result set** showing the sample data that you would like to get as a result of your query

Comment: Sorry about that, first time here. So I woud like to run a select that woud return the rows that got a test number that appears at all 3 kinds of modelo(1,2,3) so, the result woud be in this case:

Comment: 1-1-23 , 1-2-33 , 1-3-44, 2-1-32 , 2-2-31, 2-3-432

Answer (score 1):

```
select your_table.* from your_table
join (
    select test from your_table
    group by test
    having count( distinct modelo ) = (select count(distinct modelo) from your_table)
) t
on your_table.test = t.test
```

Answer (score 0):

If the number of values you want to check is 3 then this would work

```
SELECT test
FROM table_you_did_not_name
GROUP BY test
HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
```

I guess if didn't know how many modelo there were you could do this

```
SELECT test
FROM table_you_did_not_name
GROUP BY test
HAVING COUNT(*) = (
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM (SELECT DISTINCT modelo FROM table_you_did_not_name) A
)
```

Comment: Hey i dont know why, im kind of a noob, but i cant run those querrys, thats what i get: " WHERE (where) is not a valid input at this position", also i used the proper table name to run the tests, wich is "tabela", table in portuguese.

Comment: @YanWerneck, Please replace `WHERE` with `HAVING`

Comment: That did it, both methods worked, yours and Oto's. Thank you.